# Volume Mount not working with Telepresence intercept

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, telepresence

I am new to telepresence and trying to use personal interception in telepresence. I have access to running kubernetes env, where i am trying to use it learn it as well but I am unable to do telepresence interception to volume mount issue.

Things Which i am able to do

1. Able to connect telepresence using `telepresence connect`
2. Able to list all namespace in my EKS including namespace telepresence and ambassador (to verify if I don't have access level issues)
3. Able to list all interceptor using `telepresence list -n <namespace_name>`
4. Able to create telepresence intercept for workflow type `deployment` using command `telepresence intercept cards-presentation-service-cards-presentation-service --port 8080 --env-file /Users/tarun/telepresence/cards-presentation-service.env`
5. Able to start my service with important warning `docker run  -p 8080:8080  -v /var/folders/by/dc0f23dn28b91nwg4tmbgclm0000gq/T/telfs-3008985902/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/:/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ --env-file /Users/tarun/telepresence/cards-presentation-service.env 54cc4e78aa68`
6. The interception itself is working i.e. I am receiving the request at my local service when passing specific header.

Problem :

1. When running step 4, the output didn't return telepresence volume mount(however I can see that when I do `telepresence list`). When I checked the telepresence logs I see an error.

```
2022-03-15 16:27:02.2848 info    connector/session/CreateIntercept-0 : Agent found or created for Deployment cards-presentation-service-cards-presentation-service.backbase
2022-03-15 16:27:03.0567 info    connector/session/intercept-port-forward/10.0.23.237:46451 : Mounting file system for intercept "cards-presentation-service-cards-presentation-service-backbase" at "/var/folders/by/dc0f23dn28b91nwg4tmbgclm0000gq/T/telfs-3008985902"
2022-03-15 16:27:03.0658 info    connector/session/intercept-port-forward/10.0.23.237:46451 : started command /usr/local/bin/sshfs sshfs -F none -f -C -oConnectTimeout=10 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o slave -o follow_symlinks -o allow_root localhost:/tel_app_mounts /var/folders/by/dc0f23dn28b91nwg4tmbgclm0000gq/T/telfs-3008985902 : exec.pid="83584"
2022-03-15 16:27:03.3388 error   connector/session/intercept-port-forward/10.0.23.237:46451 : remote host has disconnected
2022-03-15 16:27:03.3428 info    connector/session/intercept-port-forward/10.0.23.237:46451 : ended command sshfs : exec.pid="83584"
2022-03-15 16:27:07.3519 info    connector/session/intercept-port-forward/10.0.23.237:46451 : started command /usr/local/bin/sshfs sshfs -F none -f -C -oConnectTimeout=10 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o slave -o follow_symlinks -o allow_root localhost:/tel_app_mounts /var/folders/by/dc0f23dn28b91nwg4tmbgclm0000gq/T/telfs-3008985902 : exec.pid="83606"
2022-03-15 16:27:07.3759 error   connector/session/intercept-port-forward/10.0.23.237:46451 : mount_macfuse: mount point /private/var/folders/by/dc0f23dn28b91nwg4tmbgclm0000gq/T/telfs-3008985902 is itself on a macFUSE volume
```

2. Due to above problem, the telepresence volume mount folder contain anything where I was expecting it to have folder structure of `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount` which should contain token and namespace inside it
3. Due to this when I start my service I do get this warning, meaning my local service not able to discover services using k8 discovery.

```
2022-03-15 14:17:01.196  WARN [cards-presentation-service,,] 76483 --- [           main] io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config      : Error reading service account token from: [/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token]. Ignoring.
2022-03-15 14:17:01.199  WARN [cards-presentation-service,,] 76483 --- [           main] io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config      : Error reading service account token from: [/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token]. Ignoring.
 
2022-03-15 14:20:06.145  WARN [cards-presentation-service,9a66783110c8a2fe8b6a172dfb16cb2e,51cd5acd5d2f31d9] 76483 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer      : No servers available for service: token-converter
2022-03-15 14:20:06.146  WARN [cards-presentation-service,9a66783110c8a2fe8b6a172dfb16cb2e,ee2b1ad1e0ee8e26] 76483 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.b.b.a.e.AbstractApiExceptionHandler  : Unexpected exception from API

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Instance cannot be null.
```

4. When I do ls inside the telepresence volume mount folder it says `ls: device not configured`

To me, whole problem is due to telepresence volume mount issue where folder should have contains serviceaccount details where it is failing. Any help is appreciated on this